# Alternative to array pointers in safe C#?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

I'm trying to translate a bit of C++ into C# and I can't seem to do it without losing a ton of performance due to the loss of speed in looking up and accessing array elements. I'm using 3d jagged arrays because that was the most intuitive to me at the time but I'm very open to alternate suggestions. And so my question, is there a way to access some kind of collection in the same way, or a similar way, as array pointers do? Here's a bit of the C++ I was converting:

```
void Upsample(float* from, float* to, int n, int stride)
{
    float* p, pCoeffs[4] = { 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.25 };
    p = &pCoeffs[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        to[i * stride] = 0;
        for (int k = i / 2; k <= i / 2 + 1; k++)
            to[i * stride] += p[i - 2 * k] * from[Mod(k, n / 2) * stride];
    }
}

////

for (iy=0; iy<n; iy++) for (iz=0; iz<n; iz++) {
    Upsample( &noise[i], &temp1[i], n, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Arrays in C# passes in function by reference. Everything should be OK.

Comment: Funny loop condition (int k = i / 2; k <= i / 2 + 1; k++), to me that loops always 2 times.

Comment: Can you supply your code in C# so there will be a way to detect problems in the translated code?

Comment: What is `Mod`? Why not `%`? If `Mod` is a function then likely that's where your slowdown is.